# Retrofit error when response is being parsed as list

Tags: json, retrofit2

I'm getting the following error when attempting to get a array of json objects using retrofit.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

The request is declared in the api interface as

```
interface HttpRequests {

    @GET("/api/v1/emergency")
    Observable<List<Emergency>> getEmergencies(@Query("lat") Double lat,
                                                    @Query("lng") Double lng,
                                                    @Query("dist") int dist);
```

Where Emergency is defined as

```
public class Emergency {

    @SerializedName("emergencyUuid")
    @Expose
    private String emergencyUuid;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private Double lat;
    @SerializedName("lng")
    @Expose
    private Double lng;
    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    @Expose
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Emergency(){};
    public Emergency(String emergencyUuid, Double lat, Double lng, String phoneNumber){
        this.emergencyUuid = emergencyUuid;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    // getters & setters

}
```

When I replace the `List<Emergency>` with `String` I can print the response which looks somewhat like:

```
"[{\"emergencyUuid\":\"axkdjfiwokdfj\",\"lat\":22.22,\"lng\":33.33,\"phoneNumber\":\"12345678910\"}]"
```

This seems to me a perfectly fine json array with a single emergency object. I do not understand why this can't be parsed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like json that has been escaped and put into a string.  If you have access to the server, you should look to see if you are encoding you object twice.

Comment: @iagreen You were right. That was a silly one.